# Difference between sumbool and sum

Tags: coq

For any `A B : Prop`, `sum A B` and `sumbool A B` are isomorphic, by the following,

```
Definition from_sumbool (A B : Prop) (x : sumbool A B) : sum A B :=
  match x with
  | left l => inl l
  | right r => inr r
  end.

Definition to_sumbool (A B : Prop) (x : sum A B) : sumbool A B :=
  match x with
  | inl l => left l
  | inr r => right r
  end.
```

So why do we have `sumbool` ? It seems a mere restriction of `sum`, where `A B` are `Prop` instead of `Type` and the result is `Set` instead of `Type`.

And "bool" sounds like the sumbools have 2 elements. However that's only the case of `sumbool True True`. `sumbool False False` and `sumbool False True` have 0 and 1 elements respectively.

Also for `A B : Prop`, the OCaml extractions of `sum A B` are more verbose than those of `sumbool A B`. I don't see a clear reason for that : we assumed the extraction knows the type of `A` and `B` is `Prop`, so it could use the same simplifications as `sumbool` in this case.

Often it seems Coq defines the same function 3 times : for `Type`, `Set` and `Prop`. It does this for all induction schemes of inductive types (`_rect`, `_rec` and `_ind`). And here for the disjoint union, we have `sum`, `sumbool` and `or`. That makes 3 times more functions to remember.

Comment: The difference in extraction is necessary because `sum` can be used with non-`Prop` types. Apart from this detail about extraction, I can't think of another reason for having both `sum` and `sumbool`.

Comment: See also some discussion in [PR #306](https://github.com/coq/coq/pull/306).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In part, I think it's simply that `sumbool` is intended to serve a different purpose than `sum`, and the unique name and notation are used to highlight and document this fact.

A `sum` is just a generic sum type, but a `sumbool` is intended to serve as a boolean-like result where the "true" and "false" values carry evidence.  So, when you see a library function like:

```
Definition le_lt_dec n m : {n <= m} + {m < n}.
```

it's clear that the *purpose* of such a definition is to construct a boolean-like decision value that we can use in computations just like `leb : nat -> nat -> bool`, but that will also have evidence available in each conditional branch.

As a more practical matter, the type `sumbool : Prop -> Prop -> Set` allows the `Prop` evidence to be erased at compile/extraction time, in a way that won't happen for the more general `sum` type.

As an admittedly silly example, if we had a `head` function that required evidence of non-zero list length:

```
Lemma nlt_0_r : forall n, ~(n < 0). Proof. intros n H. inversion H. Qed.
Definition head {A : Set} (l : list A) (E : 0 < length l) : A :=
  match l return (0 < length l -> A) with
  | x :: _ => fun _ => x
  | nil => fun E1 => except (nlt_0_r _ E1)
  end E.
```

and we wanted to write a `head_with_default` definition, it might be natural to use a `sumbool`:

```
Definition head_with_default {A : Set} (x : A) (l : list A) :=
  match le_lt_dec (length l) 0 : {length l <= 0} + {0 < length l} with
  | left _ => x
  | right E => head l E
  end.
```

We could also write it with a plain `sum` type:

```
Definition le_lt_dec' (n m : nat) : (n <= m) + (m < n). Admitted.
Definition head_with_default' {A : Set} (x : A) (l : list A) :=
  match le_lt_dec' (length l) 0 : (length l <= 0) + (0 < length l) with
  | inl _ => x
  | inr E => head l E
  end.
```

and if we extract these two definition, we can see that the evidence is erased from the `sumbool` version but still carried around in the `sum` version:

```
Extraction head_with_default.
(* let head_with_default x l = *)
(*   match le_lt_dec (length l) O with *)
(*   | Left -> x *)
(*   | Right -> head l *)

Extraction head_with_default'.
(* let head_with_default' x l = *)
(*   match le_lt_dec' (length l) O with *)
(*   | Inl _ -> x *)
(*   | Inr _ -> head l *).
```

**Update:**  Following up to a comment, note that this difference in extraction isn't really an "optimization".  It's not like Coq saw that -- in this particular case -- the `Prop`s in the `sumbool` could be optimized away but then failed to perform the same optimization in `sum` because the compiler wasn't smart enough.  It's that the entire Coq logic is built on the idea that in the `Prop` universe proof values can and will be erased but in the `Set` universe "proof" values are important and will be reflected at runtime.

**Further update:** Now, you might very well ask (as you did, in further comments), why *isn't* this an optimization at the extraction level?  Why not use a single `sum` type in Coq and then change the extraction algorithm so that it erases all types that are known at compile time to be `Prop`s.  Well, let's try it.  Suppose, using the definitions above, we write:

```
Inductive error := empty | missing.
Definition my_list := (inr 1 :: inr 2 :: inl missing :: inr 4 :: nil).
Definition sum_head := head_with_default' (inl empty) my_list.
```

The extraction looks like this:

```
type ('a, 'b) sum =
| Inl of 'a
| Inr of 'b

(** val my_list : (error, nat) sum list **)
let my_list = ...

(** val sum_head : (error, nat) sum **)
let sum_head =
  head_with_default' (Inl Empty) my_list
```

Now, the naive extraction of `head_with_default'` was as above.  If we want to write out an optimized version, we can't re-use the type `sum`, since its constructors have the wrong arity.  We'll need to generate an optimized `sum` type with erased props:

```
type sumP =
| InlP
| InrP

let head_with_default' x l =
  match le_lt_dec' (length l) O with
  | InlP -> x
  | InrP -> head l
```

This works okay.  Of course, if someone tries to create a `nat + (x == 0)`, also known as a `sumor`:

```
Definition nat_or_zero (x : nat) : nat + (x = 0) :=
  match x with
  | O => inr eq_refl
  | _ => inl x
  end.
```

then we'll need a third version of the `sum` type:

```
type ('a) sumSP =
| InlSP of 'a
| InrSP

let nat_or_zero x = match x with
| O -> InrSP
| S _ -> InlSP x
```

and we'll need a forth version `sumPS` unless we have a good reason to reject `(x==0) + nat`.

Any function that could potentially operate on `sum`s, such as:

```
Fixpoint list_lefts {A B : Type } (l : list (A + B)) : list A :=
  match l with
  | nil => nil
  | inr x :: l' => list_lefts l'
  | inl x :: l' => x :: list_lefts l'
  end.
```

would also need to be extracted in multiple versions.  At least for `A : Set`, both `B : Set` and `B : Prop` might be potentially useful:

```
(** val list_lefts : ('a1, 'a2) sum list -> 'a1 list **)

let rec list_lefts = function
| Nil -> Nil
| Cons (s, l') ->
  (match s with
   | Inl x -> Cons (x, (list_lefts l'))
   | Inr _ -> list_lefts l')

(** val list_leftsSP : ('a1) sumSP list -> 'a1 list **)

let rec list_leftsSP = function
| Nil -> Nil
| Cons (s, l') ->
  (match s with
   | InlSP x -> Cons (x, (list_lefts l'))
   | InrSP -> list_lefts l')
```

You could argue that the other two aren't useful, but what if someone disagrees with you and tries to apply `list_lefts'` to a `list ((x=0)+(x=1))` anyway?  Obviously, a first crack at an optimized version doesn't work at eliminating `__`:

```
(** val list_leftsP : sum' list -> __ list **)

let rec list_leftsP = function
| Nil -> Nil
| Cons (s, l') ->
  (match s with
   | InlP -> Cons (__, (list_lefts l'))
   | InrP -> list_lefts l')
```

but this is merely because we haven't extracted an optimized version of `list`:

```
type listP =
| NilP
| ConsP of listP
```

to let us write:

```
(** val list_leftsP : sumP list -> listP **)

let rec list_leftsP = function
| Nil -> NilP
| Cons (s, l') ->
  (match s with
   | InlP -> ConsP (list_leftsP l')
   | InrP -> list_leftsP l')
```

which reveals that `list_leftsP` (and the forth variant I've left out) **is** potentially useful, as it performs the non-trivial computation of calculating the number of proofs of `x=1` in a given `l : list ((x=0) + (x=1))`.

Now we're ready to define:

```
Definition ugh {A B C D : Type} : A + B -> C + D ->
  A*C + A*D + B*C + B*D := ...
```

and use one of its 16 versions, like `ughPPPS`, together with a subset of the four versions of `prod` to represent its result.  However, it's not clear if the ML return type of `ughPPPS` should be the naive:

```
(((prodP ('d prodPS) sum) prodP sum) ('d prodPS) sum)
```

which fails to erase useless terms of type `prodP`, or if it should instead be optimized to:

```
(((('d prodPS) sumPS) sumSP) ('d prodPS) sum)
```

Indeed, Coq could have gone this route, inductively tracing the dependence of types on `Props` versus `Sets` and generating multiple extractions as necessary for all the variants used in a program.  Instead, it requires the programmer to decide at the Coq level which proofs are important (`Set`) or unimportant (`Prop`) and -- all too frequently -- requires multiple variants of types, constructors, and functions to deal with (some of) the combinations.  The result is that the extraction will closely mirror the Coq types, rather than being a `fooPPSPPSP` salad of optimized variants.  (A big advantage, if you're trying to use the extraction in any non-Coq code.)

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer. As I was saying, the extraction of `head_with_default'` looks like a bug. Agreed, `sum` works with any `Type`s, but here they are `n <= m` and `m < n`. It knows at compile-time that they are `Prop`s, so could erase them. Besides, I apologize I'm not good enough at Coq, but `le_lt_dec` and `le_lt_dec'` look exactly the same to me, both in notation and in intent. The intent comes from using `+` instead of `\/`, which places the result in sort `Type` rather than `Prop` and constrains the allowed `match`es.

Comment: I guess the point is that Coq uses `{n=0} + {n<>0}` to represent a decidable dichotomy between propositions with the convenience of carrying around evidence and `nat + nat*nat` to represent a sum type where the values of both halves are potentially important.  The standard library doesn't use `(n=0) + (n<>0)` for much the same reason it doesn't define `nat := list unit`; the intended use is different.  I guess if you're generally concerned that the Coq standard library should be built up out of the minimum possible number of orthogonal constructs, `sumbool` seems like a weird place to start.

Comment: What type does the extraction use to represent a proof in OCaml? In `head_with_default'` the proofs are simply discarded with underscores. Do you have an example of how to use a proof in OCaml?

Comment: Well, as you probably know, proofs are represented as OCaml terms.  Trivially, `x` and `l` in the above example are proofs of `A` and `list A` respectively whose values are used.  Proofs of propositions, though, are extracted as the symbol `__` of value bottom and unit type.  As they are not particularly useful, it's wise to avoid introducing them into the extraction, for example by using a `sumbool` in place of a `sum`!

Comment: Honestly, I'm trying to understand your answer. If it is wise to avoid leaking `__` in extracted OCaml code, why not change the extraction algorithm, so that it erases all `Type`s that are known at compile-time to be `Prop`s?

Comment: I've added some more detail to address your follow-up comment.